# Formula for computing probabilities of final outcomes when a coin is flipped between two lotteries

Tags: probability, finance

This is from Markowitz's Risk-Return Analysis: The Theory and Practice of Rational Investing (Volume One) Chapter 1.

There are 3 lottery tickets one can choose from:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline Alternatives & Chances & Outcome \\ \hline A & 1/1000 & $1000 \\ \hline  & 999/1000 & $0 \\ \hline B & 1/100 & $100 \\ \hline  & 99/100 & $0 \\ \hline C & 1/2000 & $1000 \\ \hline  & 1/200 & $100 \\ \hline  & 1989/2000 & $0 \\ \hline  \end{array}

And the formula for computing the probabilities of final outcomes when a coin is flipped between lotteries A & B yields

$$P_{$1000} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{2000} = \frac{1}{2000} $$
$$P_{$100} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{20}{1000} = \frac{10}{1000} $$
$$P_{00} = 1 - P_{$1000} - P_{$100} $$
$$ = \frac{1989}{2000} $$

I'm having trouble understanding this. So there are 3 different probabilities here. The first one, $P_{$1000}$ is the probability of the outcome being $1000$ dollars, which is (the probability of getting lottery A from the coin flip) x (the probability of the outcome being $1000$ dollars). That makes sense from the table above. But the second one, $P_{$100}$, the probability of the outcome being $100$ dollars should be $\frac{20}{2000}$ or $\frac{1}{100}$. Why then is it $\frac{20}{1000}$???

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos, and this might be clearer

$$P_{\$1000} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1000} = \frac{1}{2000} $$
$$P_{\$100} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{100} = \frac{1}{200}= \frac{10}{2000} $$
$$P_{00} = 1 - P_{\$1000} - P_{\$100} \\=\frac{2000}{2000}-\frac{1}{2000}-\frac{10}{2000}  \\= \frac{1989}{2000} $$

Comment: Thanks Henry. What you wrote makes sense. But just to be clear, where are my typos? If I have typos then Markowitz has typos. But are you absolutely sure it's a typo?

Comment: @Karen You wrote $P_{\$100} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{20}{1000}$ rather than $P_{\$100} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{10}{1000}$  or $P_{\$100} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{20}{2000}$ but your result of $\frac{1989}{2000}$ suggests you must have used a correct version

Comment: Like I said, I copied it from Markowitz' book exactly as he has it. So if what you say is a typo, it means that Markowitz' has a typo, which is kind of rare in these sorts of texts. So I just wanted to make sure that it is indeed a typo, and I'm not going crazy.